# Current link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already tried many example of current link active when clicked, but none of them work for me. I have some link and each link will load the content when clicked.
What I want is after I clicked the link, the style still there even after content is refresh.
This is my index.html

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post" action="index.html">
    <div id="sorting">
        <ul>
            <li href="#" class="sort">Sort By</li>
            <li class="sort-by-doc by">
                <a href="#" id="1" onclick="setSorting(this.id)" th:text="#{sort.doc}"></a>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="sort-by-date by">
                <a href="#" id="2" onclick="setSorting(this.id)" th:text="#{sort.date}"></a>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="sort-by-po by">
                <a href="#" id="3" onclick="setSorting(this.id)" th:text="#{sort.po}"></a>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sortBy" th:value="${sortBy}"></input>
</form>
```

I've added this script

```
$('#sorting li').click(function() {
    $('li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Yes, missed `$` in `('li.current').removeClass('current');`

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors before posting to SO.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed `$` in here, but actually in my code there's `$`. And that's didn't work.

Comment: Have you wrapped code in `ready` if the script is loaded in `<head>` or the `li` elements are added dynamically? Also, you need to add `event.preventDefault();` in the handler.

Comment: @Tushar I already wrap the code in `ready`. And what `event.preventDefault();` using for? how to do I add the code?

Comment: @DevanJ. Try `$('#sorting').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    $('li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    e.preventDefault();
});`.

Comment: @Tushar It's not working, In the css I just add this code right? `#sorting ul li.current {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:red;
}`

Comment: @DevanJ. Create live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Tushar I made the jsfiddle, but it's working, but when I try in my project (web app), it's didn't work. For ex. this is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kee6pyL6/) I don't know why in my project the script didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggesting to make it like this:

```
$('#sorting li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

Comment: I'd say use, `.siblings('.current')`

Comment: @tushar Works just fine, here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/350D/8Lm1yksL/) example